# How would I update battery charging status every second

Tags: java, xml, timer, threadpool

I am developing a mobile app  which keeps the screen  ON when launched and all of you know that this kind of app drains the battery. So I wanted to keep the screen ON only when the device is plugged in. I found this code on stackoverflow (thanks to all of you).

```
  IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
  Context context = this;
  Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
  int status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
  boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING || status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;
  int chargePlug = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
  boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
  boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;
  if (isCharging) {
    if (usbCharge) {
      tv1.setText("USB plugged in");
    } else {
      if (acCharge) {
        tv1.setText("AC plugged in");
      }
    }
  } else {
    tv1.setText("Connect your charger");
  }
}
```

I put this code in oncreate. But the problem is that it shows status only once(when app is launched). So I put a timer task to repeat checking like this

```
t = new TimerTask() {
    @Override 
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
              @Override 
              public void run() {
                  IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
                  Context context = this;
                  Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
                  int status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
                  boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING || status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;
                  int chargePlug = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
                  boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
                  boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;
                  if (isCharging) {
                    if (usbCharge) {
                      tv1.setText("USB plugged in");
                    } else {
                      if (acCharge) {
                        tv1.setText("AC plugged in");
                      }
                    }
```

But this doesn't work and gives the error

> Type missmatch : Cannot convert from new Runnable(){} to Context

I am a newbie so please see if you could help me with some modification or even a new code. Thanks in advance.
Important note: I work on Sketchware which lets you only to put codes in MainActivity.xml or MainActivity.java other features like manifest.xml is not editable. Please keep this in mind while answering.

Comment: You can use a BroadcastReceiver to get Battery Status in every second.

Answer (score 0):

Use Broadcast Receiver to get Battery Status.
Like That:-

```
// Initialize a new BroadcastReceiver instance
private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {            
        int status=intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS,-1);            
        if(status==BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING)
        {
            //Do anything if Charging
        }
        else
        {
            //Do anything if not Charging
        }
    }
}
```

Call it Like That:-

```
// Get the application context
Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
// Initialize a new IntentFilter instance
IntentFilter iFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
// Register the broadcast receiver
mContext.registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver,iFilter);
```

Hope this will help you!!!

Comment: From the battery status, I mean battery charging stauts only. i.e to check if "Charging" or "Not Charging".

Comment: I have edited code now you can get charging status of battery with it.

Comment: I tried it like this: ifilter, broadcast, register, override, and then the if condition but not working. Please if you could provide the full code in a sequence so i can just copy and paste.